# How to install AMD Catalyst 15.9 on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel-modules, fglrx, amd-graphics

today I tried to install the fglrx-updates package from the repositories of Ubuntu 15.10, but after rebooting my computer, did not start the display manager.

It is assumed that the driver has patches to support version 4.2 of the kernel, but for some reason does not work on Ubuntu 15.10.

If someone has managed to install it, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

After several failed attempts, I finally managed to install the driver AMD 15.9 on ubuntu 15.10.

The following steps are aimed at allowing the user to install the driver on ubuntu 15.10 and any of its flavors.

The following steps are performed on a fresh install of ubuntu 15.10.

1. Install the driver:

> sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates gcc-4.9 g++-4.9

2. Create links to gcc:

> sudo rm -f /usr/bin/gcc
>
> sudo rm -f /usr/bin/g++
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 /usr/bin/gcc
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.9 /usr/bin/g++

3. Rebuild the driver module.:

> sudo apt-get --reinstall install fglrx-updates-core

After completing the above steps, you can create a configuration file as follows:

> sudo aticonfig --initial

That is enough to make install the ubuntu 15.10 and AMD in any of its flavors.

**Warning: Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 users on laptops. At the moment I have not patched and recompiled mutter for that version of ubuntu to make it possible to install the driver, so its use in laptops is not recommended.**

Comment: Thanks, I tried this one, but I still get a black screen after the Kubuntu splash screen. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to this link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1493888/comments/183

This is the official workaround till the fix will be released.

[Bug #1493888](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1493888) states

> The fglrx driver is not compatible with gcc 5.x. This causes the kernel module to crash on initialisation. As a result, users will boot into a black screen, as X will fail (except on Intel+AMD hybrid systems, where intel is used).